# codename one image chooser gives wrong path

Tags: codenameone

I want to upload an image with codename one the issue is when i upload it i get the wrong image name and path , let me explain more so this is the code :

```
 imaged.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            Display.getInstance().openImageGallery(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                    if (ev != null && ev.getSource() != null) {
                        String filePath = (String) ev.getSource();
                        int fileNameIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf("/") +1;
                        String fileName = filePath.substring(fileNameIndex);
                        System.out.println("image     : "+  fileName);


                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    c3.add(imaged);
```

i want to get the image name to insert it into my data base the lint that i gott is :

```
C:/Users/Emel/AppData/Local/Temp/temp8005230168902905005..png
```

the image which i'm selecting is hosted on my wamp server under the www folder:

```
http://localhost/PiWeb1/TeamFlags/es.png
```

which is wrong even the file name is wrong how can i get the real path and file name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit problematic on devices. They are very inconsistent when it comes file system/media so we try to replicate some of those problems in the simulator by copying the selection to the side.

The reason is simple, say you had access to the image directory of the phone you could read and upload all the images without the users consent. So they OS copies an image and gives you access only to that data.

You might have better luck with this on devices, if not you might have better luck with: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-file-open-dialogs.html

As a side note your URL won't be an http URL it will be a file URL.

Comment: Ok ! i found another solution i tried to create a copy of the image in my server  folder i know it's not the best solution but i ll try to improve it , now the problem is that the builder doesn't accept the java.io.* package in  my CN1 project , i'm tryin to copy the image from the temprary folder to the server folder it works in a simple java project but in the CN1 the compile failed , Any idea how to resolve this issue ! ?